# Run an init script/code-block before running main in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Is there a way to execute a python script or static code-block before the actual main function is invoked in PyCharm? I have a small piece of initialization code (specific to my **personal** dev environment) that needs to be executed before the main function and I **cannot** change the module that has `main()` since it is not a piece of code that I own.

Comment: There is no `main()` in Python.
if you mean `if __name__ == "__main__":`
just place code above

Comment: yea `if __name__ == "__main__"` is what I meant. I can't change the file that has `main`.

Answer (score 2):

Add your module in `Before launch`, by editing run config
[image: img]

Comment: will this run in the same process as the script?